# passing reference pointing to struct as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, embedded

I would like effectively map structures with registers to a memory.
Actually I have working code like this:

Structure with registers for a peripheral:

```
struct Periph {
    volatile uint32_t REG1;
    volatile uint32_t REG2;
};
```

In device is this peripheral two times located on two different addresses in memory, so define these addresses:

```
static constexpr size_t PERIPH1_BASE = 0x40000000;
static constexpr size_t PERIPH2_BASE = 0x40001000;
```

Then I have a driver which can use any of these registers:

```
template<size_t Base> struct Driver {
    inline Periph &r() {
        return *reinterpret_cast<Periph *>(base);
    }
    void setFoo(uint32_t x) {
        r().REG1 = x;
    }
    uint32_t getBar() {
        return r().REG2;
    }
};
```

To use this driver is simple, only need set address of certain peripheral to template:

```
Driver<PERIPH1_BASE> drv;
uint32_t x = drv.getBar();
drv.setFoo(x);
...
```

If compiler merge all inline functions after optimization then this method works very effectively with registers and without any overhead.

But this is not very safe, because I can set to `Driver` any address from different peripheral.

My Idea to improve this is to put reference to a structure as template argument, but without success.

First I defined references to registers:

```
static Periph &PERIPH1 = *reinterpret_cast<Periph *>(PERIPH1_BASE);
static Periph &PERIPH2 = *reinterpret_cast<Periph *>(PERIPH2_BASE);
```

This is working, I can directly access these registers like:

```
PERIPH2.REG1 = 123;
```

But I have no idea how to pass these references to template argument, my attempt is following:

```
template<Periph &r> struct Driver {
    void setFoo(uint32_t x) {
        r.REG1 = x;
    }
    uint32_t getBar() {
        return r.REG2;
    }
};

Driver<PERIPH2> drv;
drv.setFoo(x);
```

From this I get following error:

```
`error: the value of 'PERIPH2' is not usable in a constant expression`
```

If I define PERIPH2 as constexpr then I get another error:

```
`error: reinterpret_cast from integer to pointer`
```

... So how to put reference to an object as template argument?
Or an idea or suggestion to make this better.

*Also here exists lot of other solutions (like put reference to a Driver constructor...), but this slow down access to registers.*

Thanks for any help.

Comment: did you try `boost::ref` or `std::ref`?

Comment: no boost, no std, it is embedded on small MCUs with lack of memory

Comment: frankly, I think your first approach is fine

Comment: @vlk Did you already try `static const Periph &PERIPH2 = ...`?

Comment: is using a wrapper class appropriate for you?

Comment: Or maybe instead of defining an inline function returning reference, you can use a `Periph` reference member and initialize it using the template argument? It would be faster than dereferencing the pointer every time you want to access the device. Maybe you even don't need template parameters. Just pass the Base to the ctor, and dereference in ctor only once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But I have no idea how to pass these references to template argument

Because they are different things. As I understood, this might help you: use your peripherals structures as singletones with incapsulated base addresses.

```cpp
template<std::size_t Base>
struct periph {

    static constexpr periph volatile& instance() {
        return *reinterpret_cast<periph volatile*>(Base);
    }

    template<std::size_t N>
    static constexpr std::uint32_t volatile& reg() {
        return periph::instance().reg_[N];
    }

    // prohibit instance constructing
    periph() = delete; 
    periph(periph const&) = delete;
    periph(periph&&) = delete;

private:

    uint32_t reg_[2];
};
```

You can access registers via `instance()` or `reg<>()` methods. For example:

```
periph<0x00001000>::reg<0>() = 0;
```

Now, make your `Driver`'s template argument to take type not value:

```cpp
template<typename Periph>
struct driver {
    using periph_type = Periph;

    // for example
    void foo() {
        periph_type::reg<0>() = 1234;
    }
};
```

Look, `Periph::instance()` is reference you wanted to pass. As you can see, `driver::foo()` uses `Periph`-defined static method `Periph::reg<>()` to access peripheral instance instead of explicit addresses. Looks more safer.

Also you can discard default template implementation and implement specializations:

```cpp
using periph1 = periph<0x40000000>;
using periph2 = periph<0x40001000>;

template<typename Periph>
struct driver;

template<>
struct driver<periph1> {
    // specialization for periph1 only
};

template<>
struct driver<periph2> {
    // specialization for periph2 only
};
```

Or

```
template<std::size_t Base>
struct driver< periph<Base> > {
    // use periph<Base> here
};
```

For *another* (not the same as `periph`) peripheral you should implement *another* type (for example, `i2c<>`). Probably, in the same manner as `periph<>` implemented (with incapsulated address as template parameter). But if you deal with multiple same-typed peripherals (for example, multiple *CAN* buses) you should/might use the same type with different `Base`s.

**UPDATE:**

Also, you might want to look on this implementation:

```
template<std::size_t Base>
struct periph {
private:
    struct context {
        std::uint32_t reg[2];
    };

    static constexpr context volatile& ctx() {
        return *reinterpret_cast<context volatile*>(Base);
    }

public:

    static volatile std::uint32_t & REG1;
    static volatile std::uint32_t & REG2;
};

template<std::size_t Base>
volatile std::uint32_t & periph<Base>::REG1 = ctx().reg[0];

template<std::size_t Base>
volatile std::uint32_t & periph<Base>::REG2 = ctx().reg[1];
```

In this case address (`Base`) is still incapsulated into `struct periph` but registers might be accessed as static members:

```
periph<0> p;
p.REG1 = 1;

periph<0>::REG1 = 0;
```

Comment: All your suggestions are very interesting. I like mostly the first idea with singleton and sending into template type instead of reference..., the second is also good, but need repeat register definitions in `.cpp` and I prefer only header files. Thanks.